Allow decimal in an input (Angula)
i am working in a little project with Angular but i face the next problem, the input from a form don´t let me introduce decimal, like 23.5, i don´t know if something is wrong, please help with this problem, this is the code:
              <div class="form-group" *ngIf="bolivaresVisible" [ngClass]="{'has-error': cuenta.get('bolivares')?.invalid && cuenta.get('bolivares')?.touched}">
                <label for="bolivares{{i}}">{{ cuenta.get('currency')?.value === 'bolivares' ? 'Bolívares' : 'Pesos' }} <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <div class="input-button-group">
                  <input id="bolivares{{i}}"
                  type="text"
                  inputmode="decimal"
                  [formControlName]="cuenta.get('currency')?.value === 'bolivares' ? 'bolivares' : 'pesos'"
                  placeholder="Ingrese cantidad"
                  (input)="onBolivaresOrPesosInput($event, i)">
                  <button mat-icon-button type="button" (click)="toggleCurrency(i)">
                    <mat-icon>swap_horiz</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

Ts
 onBolivaresOrPesosInput(event: Event, index: number): void {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    let inputValue = inputElement.value;

    // Permitir solo un punto decimal y dígitos
    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    const parts = inputValue.split('.');
    if (parts.length > 2) {
      parts[1] = parts.slice(1).join('');
      inputValue = parts.slice(0, 2).join('.');
    }
    inputElement.value = inputValue;

    const numericValue = parseFloat(inputValue);

    const control = this.cuentasDestinatarioArray.controls[index];

    if (!isNaN(numericValue)) {
      if (control.get('currency')?.value === 'bolivares') {
        control.get('bolivares')?.setValue(numericValue, { emitEvent: false });
      } else if (control.get('currency')?.value === 'pesos') {
        control.get('pesos')?.setValue(numericValue, { emitEvent: false });
      }
    } else {
      // Si no es un número válido, establecer el valor como null o ''
      if (control.get('currency')?.value === 'bolivares') {
        control.get('bolivares')?.setValue(null, { emitEvent: false });
      } else if (control.get('currency')?.value === 'pesos') {
        control.get('pesos')?.setValue(null, { emitEvent: false });
      }
    }
    this.updateLabelsBasedOnInputs();
  }


I have an onBolivaresOrPesosInput method that handles the input event. It attempts to format the input to allow only digits and one decimal point.

The method updates the form control value based on the currency type (bolivares or pesos).

In the HTML, I'm using a form control with inputmode="decimal" and binding it to the appropriate form control name based on the selected currency.

There's also a button to toggle between currencies.


Despite these implementations, users are unable to input decimal values as intended. The input seems to be rejecting or not properly handling decimal points.
I've tried using regular expressions to clean the input and allow for one decimal point, but it's not working as expected. Here's a snippet of the relevant code:
Any insights on why decimal inputs might not be working and how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Any reason to have input type as text?
